# How to fix [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null" (found in <Root>)?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, dom, checkbox

I have a checkbox, when user marks it, vue.js data with property `accepted`  changes from false to true.

I want to hide some HTML elements if `accepted = true`.
I trying to get element by id and set `display: none`.
I am getting `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`. I guess this is because my function is executed before the page is fully loaded.

How could I fix it?

Thank you

**HTML**

```
       <div id="acceptedTrue" >
         <form action="" class="AGBcheckbox" >
           <input
             id="checkbox"
             onkeyup="agbValidate('checkbox')"
             v-model="newContract.accepted"
             class="AGBcheckboxInput"
             type="checkbox"
             name="AGB"
             value="AGB"
           />

           <label for="AGB">
             I agree the terms and conditions
           </label>
         </form>
       </div>
```

**vue.js**

```
    new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
      data() {
        return {
          newContract: {
            postcode: "",
            accepted: false,
            accepted_by: "",
          },
        };
      },
      methods: {
        changeAGBview() {         
          if(this.newContract.accepted = true)  {
            document.getElementById("acceptedTrue").style.display = "none"
            }
        }
      },
      mounted() {
      this.changeAGBview()
     }
```

Comment: `this.newContract.accepted = true` is always true. Use `if ( this.newContract.accepted )`. --- Use ` <div id="acceptedTrue" v-if="!newContract.accepted" >` and remove the changeAGBView method. But why do you want to hide the checkbox if someone has accepted the AGB. As a customer I would exit the page imediately, if my confirmation vanishes and I would never come back like the checkbox. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use `v-if`:

```
   <div id="acceptedTrue" v-if="!newContract.accepted">
     <form action="" class="AGBcheckbox" >
       <input
         id="checkbox"
         onkeyup="agbValidate('checkbox')"
         v-model="newContract.accepted"
         class="AGBcheckboxInput"
         type="checkbox"
         name="AGB"
         value="AGB"
       />

       <label for="AGB">
         I agree the terms and conditions
       </label>
     </form>
   </div>
```

By the way, since your new Vue instance is attached to the element with id `#app`, make sure that you wrap your `html` inside that this element.